# How to ssh with public-key on an iPad?

Tags: terminal, ipad, applications, ssh, remote-desktop

I want to use an iPad to connect to a linux server through ssh. However, the server only accepts encrypted access using public-key authentication. Is there any way to do that?

So one question is what app to ssh. The other is how and where to put the key.

I basically want to use vim on the server. And optionally, if possible, gnuplot is also helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice free app [Termius](https://termius.com/) that fulfills the need well. (No X forwarding.) It works with secure key login. An annoying thing is that the connection dies out after a few minutes if you start to use other apps. I don't know how to set this timeout limit. Not sure if this is common to other ssh apps.

Comment: Same for me. Great app, but annoying to have to login again after leaving to use another app.

Comment: @BritMansell I later found out that one can actually prevent the app session from being timed out: [check this](https://docs.termius.com/faq/troubleshooting/cant-run-in-the-background).

Comment: Thanks, @xiaohuamao! That works well.

Answer (score 2):

This is totally feasible.

I would start with an app like prompt by panic that has excellent quality, proper documentation and first rate support.

- https://www.panic.com/prompt/

They say shockingly good software, and I’ve found that to be an understatement as a happy customer for years, paying for many of their products. Prompt is a 5 star app in my book, best of the best for ssh from iOS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Does it come with X forwarding? Gnuplot needs that.

Comment: @xiaohuamao That’s not really ssh, so I use Screens app when I need X11 server running and bring the display to the iOS device. https://help.edovia.com/hc/en-us/categories/360000237893-Screens There have been a handful of X11 servers on the App Store, but they all seem to run into licensing issues and get pulled by the developer (or no one pays enough). See [Mocha X11 Lite by MochaSoft](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mocha-x11-lite/id1440418587?mt=8) for a recent arrival I have not yet tested.